# Retornar do banco de dados valores

Tags: java, jdbc

tenho duas variáveis:

```
Int id;

String Produto;
```

Quero preencher a variável "id" com valor correspondente do "produto",. Os dados são coletado direto do banco.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    connectionBancoDados con = new connectionBancoDados();
    produtoDAO dao  = new produtoDAO();
    Produto bean = new Produto();

        int id = 0;
        String prod = null;
        int quantidade = 0;
        double valor = 0;

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("PRODUTO: "+x);
        prod = x.nextLine();

        if (dao.CHECKPRODUTO(prod)) {

            id          = bean.getId();
            prod        = bean.getProduto(prod);
            quantidade  = bean.getQuantidade();
            valor       = bean.getValor();

        System.out.println("ID: "+id);
        System.out.println("PRODUTO: "+prod);
        System.out.println("QUANTIDADE: "+quantidade);
        System.out.println("VALOR: "+valor);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Iten nao cadastrado");
        }
    }
```

**SAIDA**

> ```
> uva
> ID: 0
>
> PRODUTO: null
>
> QUANTIDADE: 0
>
> VALOR: 0.0
> ```

**DAO RS**

```
 public List<Produto> RST(String produto){//Pesquisar
        Connection con = connectionBancoDados.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, produto, quantidade, valor FROM produto WHERE produto=?");
            stmt.setObject(1, produto);


            rs = stmt.executeQuery();//faz consulta noo banco e coloca no resultSet

                while(rs.next()){
                    Produto pro = new Produto();

                    pro.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    pro.setProduto(rs.getString(2));
                    pro.setValor(rs.getDouble(3));
                    pro.setQuantidade(rs.getInt(4));
                    produtos.add(pro);
                }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(produtoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            connectionBancoDados.closeConnetion(con, stmt, rs);
        }

        return produtos;
    }
```

**BEAN**

```
private int id;
    private String produto;
    private double valor;
    private int quantidade;



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(String produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getProduto();
    }
    public Object getId(String id) {
        return getId();
    }
    public String getProduto(String produto) {
        return getProduto();
    }
    public Object getQuantidade(String quantidade) {
        return getQuantidade();
    }
    public Object getValor(String valor) {
        return getValor();
    }
```

Comment: Olá! Está ocorrendo algum erro? Qual sua dificuldade? Explique na pergunta.

Comment: Você não deixou claro o erro. É o fato de estar vindo tudo zero do banco? Explica na pergunta e adiciona a informação desse registro do banco, como está armazenado lá.

Comment: Bom, não estou conseguido retornar os valores do banco a uva esta cadastrada com id, nome. quantidade e valor. quero retornas esse valores nas variáveis impressoras.

Comment: Está selecionando "id", "produto", "quantidade", e "valor", nesta ordem, mas você está guardando os valores na ordem "id", "produto", "valor", e "quantidade". Por isso eu prefiro usar os nomes dos valores, como `rs.getString("produto")` e `rs.getDouble("valor")`.

Answer (score 1):

Você recuperou os dados de um objeto que não recebeu o resultado da sua consulta ao banco de dados:

```
Produto bean = new Produto();
[...]

if (dao.CHECKPRODUTO(prod)) {
    id          = bean.getId();
    prod        = bean.getProduto(prod);
    quantidade  = bean.getQuantidade();
    valor       = bean.getValor();

    System.out.println("ID: "+id);
    System.out.println("PRODUTO: "+prod);
    System.out.println("QUANTIDADE: "+quantidade);
    System.out.println("VALOR: "+valor);
```

Se você quer imprimir o resultado retornado pelo DAO, atribua a alguma variável o valor retornado pelo método de recuperação do produto e então imprima essa variável:

```
// Aqui você troca recuperaProduto pelo nome do seu método no DAO.
bean = dao.recuperaProduto(prod);
if (bean != null) {
    id          = bean.getId();
    prod        = bean.getProduto(prod);
    quantidade  = bean.getQuantidade();
    valor       = bean.getValor();

    System.out.println("ID: "+id);
    System.out.println("PRODUTO: "+prod);
    System.out.println("QUANTIDADE: "+quantidade);
    System.out.println("VALOR: "+valor);
}
```

Comment: **SAIDA** :uva
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Model.dao.produtoDAO.RS(Ljava/lang/String;)LModel/bean/Produto;
 at test.testRS.main(testRS.java:31)
C:\Users\JPS\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 6 segundos)

Comment: Pelo log, você mudou o arquivo mas não recompilou o projeto, por isso dá erro NoSuchMethodError. Recompila e aí tenta executar novamente.

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada no meu projeto! https://github.com/jozivam/Sistema-Java